# allow pdf files to show

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

I am trying to show PDF files in my application but the `.htaccess` file does not allow to access it.

Here is code for my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/crm/(assets|css|images|pdf)  
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/crm/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|images|pdf)/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend/web/index.php/$1 [L]
```

I am unable to find issue what's going wrong with it.

Comment: What is the location, relative to your web root, of the PDF files?

Comment: i am using it for backend only for other project and the file location is "siteurl/projectfolder/common/user_document/document/abc.pdf"